# oracle sql to convert timestamp to date

Tags: sql, oracle

i have to convert different timezone string to date. in my table, i have column defined as varchar2. which contains data as below. i need to convert to one time zone(exampple to central time) and extract date from that. i tried different ways but getting invalid month error or not date. ANy suggestions from your end?

```
1/16/2020 6:28:44 AM -08:00
11/8/2019 3:20:30 AM -05:00
10/25/2019 6:08:21 PM +05:30
```

Comment: You shouldn't be storing date values in a `varchar` column to begin with. Do you have a chance to fix this broken design?

Comment: A reproducible test case with expected results would help a lot.

Comment: Do you want to take the TZ offsets into account, e.g. `6:08:21 PM +05:30` becomes `23:38:21`, or is it OK to retain the base time only as in VBoka's answer?

Comment: yes i need to consider offset as well.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I believe you first need to convert it to timestamp with timezone ad then cast it to date:

```
select CAST(to_timestamp_tz (dat_col, 'MM/DD/YYYY HH12:MI:SS AM TZH:TZM' ) AS DATE) 
from test
```

[here is a demo](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_18&fiddle=6e159baba2482381aa0f9d291ec17119)

This will turn your data into specific timezone :

```
select 
to_timestamp_tz(dat_col, 'MM/DD/YYYY HH12:MI:SS AM TZH:TZM')at time zone 'Europe/Moscow'
from test
```

Then you can cast that :

```
select 
CAST
(to_timestamp_tz(dat_col, 'MM/DD/YYYY HH12:MI:SS AM TZH:TZM')at time zone 'Europe/Moscow'
AS DATE) 
from test
```

Please provide your expected results for more accurate code...

Comment: no. you are extracting only date part. i need to convert all timezones to one timezone. then cast date from it. for example, pst 11 pm and est 1am both will have same date. but when u take date its different.

Comment: Hi @srinath Your question was not clear. That is why  WilliamRobertson asked you what is that you need and that is why you always need to give expecxted results. Also a code you have tried would be a great thing in the question too..

Comment: updated query works fine. Thank you. i marked it correct/answered. Thanks alot.

Comment: Hi @srinath, I am happy to help. You are welcome. Cheers!